# Invoicing in laravel

Tags: laravel

Does know how to use this kind of [invoicing](https://github.com/LaravelDaily/laravel-invoices), or can someone give suggestion, how to generate invoice?. Please I need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's `;extension=intl` in php.ini. change it to `extension=intl`

Comment: it showing error @Andy Song `Class 'NumberFormatter' not found`, can you help me?

Comment: I need to configure php.ini @Andy Song, but can't locate it

Comment: through XAMPP @Andy Song, the owner of the package replied to me and said that "You just need to enable this extension in php.ini by uncommenting this line: extension=ext/php_intl.dll"

Comment: I can't find the extension in the file @Andy Song

Comment: Now it showing `Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded `, @Andy Song can you please help me again?

Comment: I tried the `randomcontroller` that they have provided @Andy Song, I didn't modify it, add added a button that will redirect me to the pdf page `<button class="btn btn-success float-right" style="margin-right:5px;">
                        <a href="/contracts/generate" style="color: #ffffff">Generate PDF</a>
                    </button>`.